# Logout / Login Menu Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Jupiter theme and I added below code in theme `functions.php` to ada d menu on my Primary Menu named "Main_nav_temp". But its not working.

How can I fix it?

How can I add an element using functions.php using an Element ID as a reference?

Where I want to add the element?

```
/**
 * Add Login/Logout Menu
 */
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_inout_link', 10, 2);

function add_inout_link($items, $args){
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
         if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
             $items .= '<li><a href="' . wp_logout_url() . '">' . __( 'Logout' ) . '</a></li>';
         } else {
             $items .= '<li><a href="' . wp_login_url() . '">' . __( 'Login' ) . '</a></li>';
         }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"You must have a menu assigned to this location in your admin panel!"

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_inout_link', 10, 2);
function add_inout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
             $items .= '<li><a href="' . wp_logout_url() . '">' . __( 'Logout' ) . '</a></li>';
             } else {
             $items .= '<li><a href="' . wp_login_url() . '">' . __( 'Login' ) . '</a></li>';
             }
          }
        return $items;
}
```

Use this code. I tested this code. It is working perfectly fine. If it does not work for you, check the theme location name again.